# Spring Security/Java config - Can not login with existing user

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm learning *Spring Security* at creating simple login form. I'm using java configuration. I've in-memory users and  a simple filter chain.

But when I input an existing  *username* and *password* combination *Spring* redirect me back to login form with url: `login?error.`

This is my *Spring Security* configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

//    @Autowired
//    AuthProvider provider;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user1").password("").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("user2").password("").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("1").roles("ADMIN");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll();

    }


//    @Override
//    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
//        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
//    }
}
```

This is my JSP form:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<body>
${message}
<br>
<form method="post" action="/login">
    <input type="text" name="login"/>
    <input type="text" name="pass"/>
    <input type="submit" value="enter"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your code

```java
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user1").password("").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("user2").password("").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("1").roles("ADMIN");
}
```

replace the `@Autowired` with `@Override`

and follow this practice here [1]: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login

```
... auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("user1").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass")).roles("USER")
      .and() ...
```

using `BCryptPasswordEncoder` as follows as a bean in same code

```
    @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For admin user, try with:

```java
.withUser("admin").password("{noop}1").roles("ADMIN");
```

This is a way to store passwords in a plain text (obviously a not recommended way...). By adding `{noop}` prefix, you indicate you want to use `NoopPasswordEncoder`.

Otherwise, you should specify password encoder, for example:

```java
@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passEncoder() {
  return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

and update your `SecurityConfig` like:

```java
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passEncoder;

@Override
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(passEncoder)
                .withUser("user1").password("").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("user2").password("").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("1").roles("ADMIN");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `formLogin(String loginPage)` javadoc - default parameters for username and password are `username` and `password`. So you should reference them like that in your .jsp and then the login should work. So you should try refactoring jsp to following:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<body>
${message}
<br>
<form method="post" action="/login">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="enter"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had all three error in my code, described above. I acceped all three solutions and it works for me. Thank you!

Worked code:

My SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user1").password(passwordEncoder().encode("1")).roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("user2").password(passwordEncoder().encode("1")).roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("1")).roles("ADMIN");


    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                        .usernameParameter("login")
                        .passwordParameter("pass")
                    .permitAll();

    }

}
```

My jsp form:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<body>
${message}
<br>
<form method="post" action="/login">
    <input type="text" name="login"/>
    <input type="text" name="pass"/>
    <input type="submit" value="enter"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```